# How to add objective c xcode project into another swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am having objective c project and it has lot of classes & libraries.
I want to add this project to existing swift project but one way is, I can add bridge header write all header files names and another way I am adding Xcode project directly to another project, added dependency, header search path but unable to access project objective c file in swift.
Anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so this is possible because a project doesn't contain only classes and headers, it is bunch of settings , compatibility and etc...
As apple said in this page :

[Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Apple only mentioned files not mixing projects :

> Swift’s compatibility with Objective-C lets you create a project that contains files written in either language. You can use this feature, called mix and match, to write apps that have a mixed-language codebase. Using mix and match, you can implement part of your app’s functionality using the latest Swift features and seamlessly incorporate it back into your existing Objective-C codebase.

Comment: i try to add it in objective c framework but lot of issues are coming in that framework

Comment: You have to consider if it needs to setup framework via `pod` or it needs some other frameworks.